# How add List middle UITableViewRow

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have full screen UITableView and i need set List from Resource  in MIDDLE UITableViewRow. I attach file which show what i need. For example how i do it in Android.

```
View cell = inflater.inflate(parent, R.layout.cell, false);
for(int = 0; i < resource.length; i++) {
 cell.findViewById(R.layout.cell).addView(inflater.inflate(parent, R.layout.list_item, false))
}

return cell;
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Use stackview inside the TableCell and add dynamic views inside stackview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it.

Add a StackView which would contain your List Items.

Now your stack view's top would be to bottom of the data row at top

And your stack view's bottom would be the top of data row at bottom.

As you keep adding labels to your stackview, it would keep growing.

---

Second way to do it, in case if your itemview is going to be very dynamic and would have lots of items.

Make the item view as a table view. And disable the scrolling of the item table view. 
The constraints would be same as stack view.

And you would set tableview's height = tableview's content size.

Hope that helps